# How to render JSON from an ajax request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I have this in my view (`sales.html.erb`):

```
$('#Comprar').click(function(){    
        var table = tableToJson();    
        if (table.length == 0) 
          alert("No hay productos para comprar");
        else {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(table));
          $.ajax({
            url: "<%= products_sales_path %>",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(table),
            complete: function() {
                    alert("Done!");
                  }        
            });
        }     
      });
```

`tableToJson()` is a function that return certain information from a table already formatted like a JSON [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXuMJ.png). `products_sales_path` is the view route of `sales.html.erb`. However, I'm not sure how to use the `$.ajax()` method to send the JSON to rails server and render it. I have this in my controller (`products_controller.rb`):

```
def sales
    if request.xhr?    
      render :json => @product
    else
      @products = Product.all
      filter = params[:search]
      if filter.blank?
        @products = Product.all
      else
        @products=Product.where("lower(nombre) LIKE ? OR lower(presentacion) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
      end    
    end
  end
```

I would think that `render :json => @product` would do which I need but it doesn't work! And I haven't could figure out to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you do `p @product` what do you see in the console?

Comment: Where should I write this? In the controller? If so, in console doesn't appeard nothing special, just:
`GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:3000/products/sales [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified  8ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:3000/products/sales`

Comment: I have to assume that it was not called since nothing that could be an instance variable showed up in your console. Perhaps check the if statement?

Comment: Look my console: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv3ggbl42je7u8j/ConsoleResponse.png?dl=0] and I have written out of the if statement: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nunkuq6m4b6axt/pProduct.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this for rendering:

```
render :json => { :success => true,:product => @product.as_json() }
```

Comment: I have replaced `render :json => @product` by your code but nothing happens. I have revised the console in Firefox and it has request with get method and code 304 (Not Modified), link: `http://localhost:3000/products/sales?[{"id":"5","Nombre":"Tea","Presentación":"Botella de 500 mL","Precio":"1800.0","Cantidad ":"1","Subtotal":"1800.00"},{"nproductos":"1","precioTotal":"1800.00","fpago":"De contado"}]` But not yet render the `JSON` :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.ajax` or `$.get` to request it.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Comprar').click(function(){    
    var table = tableToJson();    
    if (table.length == 0){
      alert("No hay productos para comprar");
    } else {
      $.get("<%= products_sales_path %>", function( data ) {
        // alert("Done");
        console.log("Data: ", data);
      }, "json" );
    }
  });
})
```

**Controller:**

```
def sales
    @products = Product.all
    if request.xhr?
      render status: 200, json: {
            products: @products
      }.to_json
    else
      @products = params[:search].blank? ? @products : Product.where("lower(nombre) LIKE ? OR lower(presentacion) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
    end
end
```